# Display some fields from sharepoint 2013 list in a page and détails of this item in another page with Angular js, REST

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, item-styles, angularjs

I have a news picture Library (fields : Title, Description, Text, date, Author ), and I want to display in the first page, 5 news : the image, date and the title of the news and when I click on the title, I'm redirected to another page where I find more détails the Description of the news with the date. 
I did it with listview in c#, but I saw some blogs talking about REST and angular js [this link](http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Details/retrieve-list-data-using-angularjs-rest-api-in-sharepoint-2013-20863.aspx), but there's no title link and redirection. 
Could you please help me with some tricks?

Answer (score 0):

Again,
I found an interesting code but I don't know how to display the details in custom page not Display form. 
    [link of the code](http://www.faqssys.info/sharepoint-2013-rest-display-rich-text-field-not-working/)
In the first page, I will choose my columns with no prob, for title it's a link ( in the code I found its :

```
<td><a href="{{displayFormUrl}}?ID={{item.ID}}">{{item.Title}}</a></td>
```

But I want it like that:

```
<td><a href="www.bbbbb.apsx?ID={{item.ID}}">{{item.Title}}</a></td>
```

The problem is if I create new page (www.bbbbb.apsx) and angular code for the details how can I get id from URL and put it?